# How do I point a ListFieldIterator to a subweb when ControlMode = Display?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom page with the following [ListFieldIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.listfielditerator.aspx):

```
<SharePoint:ListFieldIterator runat="server" ControlMode="Display" OnInit="listFieldIterator_Init" />
```

Here is the Init event:

```
    protected void listFieldIterator_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListFieldIterator listFieldIterator = sender as ListFieldIterator;
        SPContext current = SPContext.Current;
        SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue(current.ListItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.URL].ToString());
        Uri uri = new Uri(value.Url);
        using (SPWeb web = current.Site.OpenWeb(uri.AbsolutePath))
        {
            SPListItem item = web.GetListItem(uri.PathAndQuery);
            if (null != item)
            {
                listFieldIterator.ItemContext = SPContext.GetContext(this.Context, item.ID, item.ParentList.ID, web);
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works great if the target List Item is in the same site as the page. But once it points to a different site, all the fields appear, but the values all appear in the following format:

> Failed to render "Title" column
>   because of an error in the "Single
>   line of text" field type control. See
>   details in log. Exception message:
>   List does not exist The page you
>   selected contains a list that does not
>   exist. It may have been deleted by
>   another user..

If I change the ControlMode to Edit, the values are displayed correctly. So how do I get it to work while in Display mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f2a93dcf-af82-4295-b17a-70f09b0036a3), [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=nl&u=http://www.mavention.nl/mavention-blog/September-2009/Microsoft-SharePoint-WebControls-and-Context.aspx&ei=CubeS9KXOYPu8wT5y8mTBw&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=39&ved=0CKQBEO4BMCY&prev=/search%3Fq%3DSetContextWeb%2BlistFieldIterator%26num%3D100%26hl%3Den%26complete%3D1), and [here](http://svengillis.blogspot.com/2009/11/experimenting-with-listfielditerator.html). The last two led me to create the following custom control which properly renders the ListFieldIterator in Display mode:

```
public class RecursiveListFieldIterator : ListFieldIterator
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
        SPControl.SetContextWeb(this.Context, this.ItemContext.Web);
        base.Render(output);
        SPControl.SetContextWeb(this.Context, web);
    }
}
```